# flutter IOS User denied permissions to access the device's location

Tags: flutter

[User denied permissions to access the device's location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dNpF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request a permission Dialog before getting Location

Comment: I did but im still getting this error message

Comment: The error said …. You don’t

Comment: Share code for more help